# How to ask extra information after login with facebook?

Tags: meteor, meteor-accounts

I have set-up the basic meteor application where I am able to login with facebook. I would like to ask for a valid phone number before actually creating the user. How do you accomplish that in meteor?
Login Workflow :

Login-page => Click 'login with facebook' => User gives permission to app => redirect back to app and ask for phone number => create user

I am using accounts-facebook and related packages.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since the Facebook API [doesn't support access to the user phone](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/user), you can't just extend the [requestPermission](http://docs.meteor.com/#/full/meteor_loginwithexternalservice) array, to ask for the user_phone.

Lets say you have this simple, login With Facebook button

```
   Meteor.loginWithFacebook({ requestPermissions: ['email']},
    function (error) {
       if (error) {
        return console.log("There was an error : " error.reason);
      }else{
        //if there is no error, lets redirect the new user to a new template
        Router.go('/registerForm')
      }
    });
```

Now that if the login was successful you can redirect the user into the `registerForm`.

**Register Form HTML**

```
<template name="registerForm">
  <!-- Simple Register Form asking for phone number -->
</template>
```

**JS Event**

```
 Template.registerForm.events({
    'submit registerForm':function(e,t){
       //code to get the input value
       var userPhoneNumber = t.$('#phoneInputValue').val()
       Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(),{$set:{'profile.phoneNumber':userPhoneNumber,'profileNumber':true}})
     }
  })
```

Did you se the boolean value `profileNumber`? with this you can use template helpers to ensure and denied access to the user if he dosnt fill the `registerForm` template(just an extra security), you can set it by default on the server side using the `Accounts.onCreateUser` method like this.

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user) {
       if(!options || !user) {
        console.log('error creating user');
        return;
    } else {
        if(options.profile) {
            user.profile.userPhoneNumber = false;
        }
    }
    return user;
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I have added clarification to the question. I wanted to ask how can I ask user to fill a form after authentication with facebook but before creating/inserting user into database.

Comment: Look, when you login with Facebook, there is a callback where we check if there is an error, so if there is no error, you can redirect the user into another template like /newForm. an do an user update like this. check answer update.

Comment: Just Confirming. So I create a user with extra flag and redirect him to my form. Once user fills the form then toggle the boolean and let him access my service. right?

Comment: Yep, its like a hard way, but thats the only way since the Facebook API dosnt support the user_phone request permission

Comment: Also i forgott to say, that a good pattern will be using a `Meteor.method` and a `Meteor.call` for the updates, with the correct `allow/deny` rules